# Перенос блока на следующую "колонку", если не влезает в текущую

Tags: html, css

Есть примерно такой код

```
<div>
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>3</p>
   <p>4</p>
   <p>5</p>
</div>

<style>
  div {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  p {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
  }

</style>
```

Очень интересно как сделать так, чтобы блоки `<p>` которые не влезают в `<div>` по высоте, переносились вправо, и так далее, чтобы получилось вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Колонки

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-column-width: 50px;
  column-width: 50px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>3</p>
   <p>4</p>
   <p>5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Flexbox

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>3</p>
   <p>4</p>
   <p>5</p>
</div>
```